# Swift - Creating a progress bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

Hi I am using this code to try and animate a progress bar based on time.

```
  import UIKit

class LoadingScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        var time = 0.0
        var timer: NSTimer

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("setProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        func setProgress() {
            time += 0.1
                progressView.progress = time / 3
            if time >= 3 {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
```

However I get an error which says: cannot sign a value of type double to a value of type float.

EDIT:

The error is on this line:

```
progressView.progress = time / 3
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Not that Xcode always gives you the right line for the error anyway ...

Comment: @Anders Here: progressView.progress = time / 3

Comment: Thank you. Please update your question with this information to make it complete (even if it is solved). This makes the quesions more useful for future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 7):

Unless told otherwise swift compiler assumes type inference of Double for 0.0 - declare as

```
var time : Float = 0.0
```

Reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html   - *Swift always chooses Double (rather than Float) when inferring the type of floating-point numbers.*

Comment: This worked to remove the error but now it crashes with the dreaded SIGABRT.  The debug console shows: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feef0708450'

Comment: this is a different problem - my best guess is you have declared your function in viewDidLoad instead of in the class - so as the console suggests, there is no selector setProgress in your class

Comment: The reason it crashes is that the code runs since @DaveRoberts fixed your problem. I would recommend you to accept his answer, and if you can't solve the new problem after debugging posting a *new* question about it.